# issue while looping a json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, json

I retrieve some option for a select from an ajax call in json format.
The code I have set up to display the new options in the select (replacing the existing ones) is the following:

```
success: function (data){
    var $select = $('#dettaglio');
    $select.html('');
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
        $select.append('<option id="' + val.id + '">' + val.text +'</option>');
    })
}
```

while the json is like this:

```
[
   {"id":"1","text":"J-Invest Spa"},
   {"id":"2","text":"J-A Holding S.r.l."},
   {"id":"3","text":"J-Invest Advisory & Servicing S.r.l."},
   {"id":"4","text":"J-Invest Immobiliare e Consulenza S.r.l."}
]
```

Running this code leads to an error that is not easy to understand:

> TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e
>
> ...===n||"function"!==n&&(0===t||"number"==typeof t&&t>0&&t-1 in
>   e)}r=b(o);var _={}...

jQuery is throwing an error but this is not helpful to see where my code is wrong. Any hint?

Comment: Is `data` in JSON format?

Comment: Yes I get an array from mysql and encode it with json_encode

Comment: @Tushar I would say it is.

Comment: would you be able to swap in the non-minimised jquery js file so that you can get a useful error message?

Comment: I see no issues in your jQuery code. [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/6kw2o8z8/)

Comment: @LelioFaieta Can you reproduce this on jsfiddle.net

Comment: `dataType:'json',`

Comment: @PranavCBalan That won't work if the headers are incorrect.

Comment: I agree with @PranavCBalan, just because you send JSON back doesn't mean it'll interpret it as JSON. Have you tried adding a JSON.parse() ?

Comment: `$.parseJSON(data)` or `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: I believe that if your MIME type is correct, the response should be implicitly parsed to JSON by jQuery. See Ismael's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Yes I get an array from mysql and encode it with `json_encode`.* The data received from the server will always be of `string` type. You need to parse it to convert to JSON format. Can you try this?

```
success: function(data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Or in case, if you are using some Old IE, you can also try:

```
success: function(data) {
  data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Comment: Actually I solved it by specifying the data type in the ajax request. I thought that jQuery could be able to detect it but it didn't

Comment: @LelioFaieta Yes, there are a lot of ways. Glad that something worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to change a bit on your PHP, by adding this:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Just that. jQuery is automatically set to detect the encoding of the returned data. If later you decide to send something else, you just change the header.

**Warning:** This function must be one of the first ones to be executed, before **ANY** output. Otherwise, it will throw errors at you.